# Не запускается собственная служба в CentOs 7

Tags: bash, centos, centos7, служба, автозагрузка

Написал простенький скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

screen -c cams
exit 0
```

Добавил в /etc/systemd/system файл record-stream.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Record Stream Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
#User=root
ExecStart=/media/Scripts/tmp.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Сделал daemon-reload. Пытаюсь запустить скрипт "systemctl start record-stream.service", но ничего не происходит. Статус выдает inactive (dead). Если просто попытаться запустить tmp.sh, то все начинает работать. В чем может быть проблема? Если нужна какая-то еще информация, прошу сообщить.

Вывод systemctl status record-stream.service:

```
● record-stream.service - Record Stream Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/record-stream.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

авг 09 11:34:54 centos2.xxx tmp.sh[30330]: Must be connected to a terminal.
авг 09 11:35:58 centos2.xxx systemd[1]: Started Record Stream Service.
авг 09 11:35:58 centos2.xxx systemd[1]: Starting Record Stream Service...
авг 09 11:35:58 centos2.xxx tmp.sh[30384]: Must be connected to a terminal.
авг 09 15:02:09 centos2.xxx systemd[1]: Started Record Stream Service.
авг 09 15:02:09 centos2.xxx systemd[1]: Starting Record Stream Service...
авг 09 15:02:09 centos2.xxx tmp.sh[3722]: Must be connected to a terminal.
авг 09 15:08:08 centos2.xxx systemd[1]: Started Record Stream Service.
авг 09 15:08:08 centos2.xxx systemd[1]: Starting Record Stream Service...
авг 09 15:08:08 centos2.xxx tmp.sh[3900]: Must be connected to a terminal.
```

Comment: Навскидку - указать полный путь к файлу `cams`?

Comment: На вид идея здравая, но не помогло. Может есть какой-то другой способ добавить в автозагрузку команду, которая через Screen выполнит скрипт?

Comment: А, ну так конечно же: `Must be connected to a terminal.`. Терминал ведь нужен. Поэтому надо как-то так: `screen -c cams -d -m` - Start screen in "detached" mode.

Comment: Попробовать запустить скрин с ключами `-dm` ? Взято отсюда: https://serverfault.com/questions/825280/after-launching-sh-script-appearing-must-be-connected-to-a-terminal

Comment: всем спасибо. ключ -dm помог, но еще изменил в файле record-stream.service Type=simple на Type=forking. И вместо пользователя root поставил другого, чтоб в Screen заходить не через sudo. Спасибо большое. Добавьте кто-нибудь ответ, я помечу его как верный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызвано это тем, что `screen` по дефолту хочет привязаться к терминалу и для этого ему нужна [$STY](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_20.html) переменная из окружения. Чтоб "обойти" это, достаточно использовать ключи `-m` (игнорировать переменную) и `-d` (detach mode)

```
#!/bin/bash

screen -dm -c cams
exit 0
```

- P.S. Уже было на **[serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/825280/after-launching-sh-script-appearing-must-be-connected-to-a-terminal)**.
- P.S. (2) Прямым текстом в `man screen`: `-d -m   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.` :)